# derivative of $\ln((1+\beta)^x-1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I differentiate the term $\ln((1+\beta)^x-1)$ with respect to $x$?

Is it possible to do it this way:

$$\frac{1}{(1+\beta)^x-1}$$

But i get stuck if i do the normal differentiation.

Comment: You need the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

You have to multiply your expression by the derivative of $(1+\beta)^x$. Note $(1+\beta)^x=\exp(x\log (1+\beta))$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\ln ((1+ \beta)^x-1)), e^y= (1+ \beta)^x-1 \\ e^y+1=(1+ \beta)^x \\  \ln (e^y+1)=x \ln (1+ \beta)$.

Hopefully you can see where to go from here.

> Implicit differentiation might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the chain rule: $$(\ln u)'=u'/u$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac d {dx} \ln ((1+\beta)^x - 1) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{(1+\beta)^x - 1} \cdot\frac d {dx}((1+\beta)^x-1) \tag{chain rule} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{(1+\beta)^x - 1} \cdot(1+\beta)^x\cdot\ln(1+\beta).
\end{align}